# How to get phone numbers of Active Directory users with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Currently I have a tenant in Azure B2C and a User flow that uses phone number and recovery e-mail to sign up a user in Active Directory. I am using the Microsoft Graph API to fetch the list of users, however, it never returns their phone number that they signed up with. If I view the users in the Active Directory portal, I see the phone number under User Principal Name.

[User as it appears in AD with the phone number under User Principal Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTt7F.png)

But in the JSON returned from the Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user) the userPrinicpalName is not the phone number but a random string (probably the OID).

```
{
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "xxxxx",
    "givenName": "xxxxx",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Saleem",
    "userPrincipalName": "cpim_38ae3f9d-8394-44fa-9ba9-6645d6454d4b@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "f5casd1e-ce6e-4c15-a36d-a710b4ca77c2"
}
```

Is there any way to get the list of users from my AD along with their phone numbers? I have also tried using a filter as follows to fetch a user by their phone number https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '+9231xxxxxxxx' and c/issuer eq 'guardianlitedev.onmicrosoft.com') but this returns an empty array. Please help! My ultimate objective is to check if a user exists against a given phone number and return their OID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem, and found that the plus (+) sign in the Filter was the problem. By encoding it with standard Url Encoding, I found success.

The `+` sign gets converted to `%2B`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '+9231xxxxxxxx' and c/issuer eq 'guardianlitedev.onmicrosoft.com')`

to

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '%2B9231xxxxxxxx' and c/issuer eq 'guardianlitedev.onmicrosoft.com')`